# ES6 Classes ability to perform polymorphism

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, polymorphism

I am trying to emulate polymorphism through ES6 Classes, in order to be able to better understand this theory.

Concept is clear (*designing objects to share behaviors and to be able to override shared behaviors with specific ones*) but I am afraid my code above is not a valid polymorphism example.

Due to my lack of experience, I appreciate if you answer these questions in a comprehensive way:

- The fact that both Classes have an equally named method, and that instances made from each Class get access correctly to their respective methods, makes this a polymorphic example?
- In case this does not emulate polimorphism, what changes should be
  done in the code for it?
- I've tried removing the `Employee.prototype = new Person();` line, and it still works. This is why I am afraid I'm not getting this concept.

```js
class Person {
  constructor (name, age) {
    this._name = name;
    this._age = age;
  }
}

Person.prototype.showInfo = function(){
  return "Im " + this._name + ", aged " + this._age;
};


class Employee {
  constructor (name, age, sex) {
    this._name = name;
    this._age = age;
    this._sex = sex;
  }
}

Employee.prototype = new Person();

Employee.prototype.showInfo = function(){
  return "Im " + this._sex + ", named " + this._name + ", aged " + this._age;
};


var myPerson = new Person('Jon', 20);
var myEmployee = new Employee('Doe', 10, 'men');

document.write(myPerson.showInfo() + "<br><br>");   // Im Jon, aged 20
document.write(myEmployee.showInfo() + "<br><br>"); // Im men, named Doe, aged 10
```

Comment: `Employee.prototype = new Person()` shouldn't be used with ES6 at all. It is roughly a thing that `extends` does, more or less. If you're interested in how JS prototypal inheritance works, I would suggest to start with ES5, because ES6 classes are syntactic sugar for existing ES5 inheritance recipes.

Comment: Subtype polymorphism is a dead end. Look into parametric/ad-hoc polymorphism instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Every JavaScript object has an internal "prototype" property, often called [[prototype]], which points to the object from which it directly inherits.

Every JavaScript function [object] has a property prototype, which is initialized with an [nearly] empty object. When you create a new instance of this function by calling it as a constructor, the [[prototype]] of that new object will point to the constructor's prototype object.

So, when you write this `var myPerson = new Person('Jon', 20);`,you have the method showInfo because you have this

```
Person.prototype.showInfo = function(){
    return "Im " + this._name + ", aged " + this._age;
};
```

With ES6 if you want to see the polymorphism you could do that :

```js
class Person {
    constructor (name, age) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
    }
        
    showInfo () {
        return "Im " + this._name + ", aged " + this._age;
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    constructor (name, age, sex) {
        super(name,age);
        this._sex = sex;
    }
        
    showInfo(){
        return "Im " + this._sex + ", named " + this._name + ", aged " + this._age;
    }
}

var myPerson = new Person('Jon', 20);
var myEmployee = new Employee('Doe', 10, 'men');

document.write(myPerson.showInfo() + "<br><br>");   // Im Jon, aged 20
document.write(myEmployee.showInfo() + "<br><br>"); // Im men, named Doe, aged 10
```

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing ES5 and ES6. Also, you simply created two classes. `Employee` does not really inherit from `Person`. The code you want should look like this:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
    }

    showInfo() {
        return `I'm ${this._name}, aged ${this._age}.`;
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    constructor(name, age, sex) {
        super(name, age);
        this._sex = sex;
    }

    showInfo() {
        return `I'm a ${this._sex} named ${this._name}, aged ${this._age}.`;
    }
}

const alice = new Person("Alice", 20);
const bob = new Employee("Bob", 25, "male");

console.log(alice.showInfo());
console.log(bob.showInfo());
```

So, here's a quick recap of what's changed.

First off, no need to assign a `prototype` anymore. Instead, you `extend` the parent class to create a child class. You can call the parent constructor using the `super()` call in the child constructor - this will set the properties that are handled by the parent ctor. Note that we don't set `name` or `age` in the child ctor anymore! This is why your example still worked after removing the line setting the child prototype: you set the properties manually anyway.

Methods are defined inside the class; no need to use the `prototype`. You override the method in the child class by just declaring it there.

Should you need any additional clarification, please ask in the comment.