# how to rewrite function so that it can be used in child classes

Tags: javascript, class, oop, asynchronous, promise

How to rewrite the function init, so that it can be placed in the parent class and called in the children. And pass the desired function to it. Because in class `GetWeatherForCurrentCity` we get a location from method `getCoordinates` and in class `GetWeatherForRandomCity` we get the location from the method `getLocation`.

```
class Weather {

    async getCoordinates(city) {
        //code
    }

    async getLocation() {
        //code
    }

    async getWeatherForecast(locationCoordinates) {
        //code
    }

    fahrenheitToCelsius(temp) {
        //code
    }

    renderForecastInfo(currently, daily) {
        //code
    }
};

class GetWeatherForCurrentCity extends Weather {

    init() {
        this.getLocation().then((location) => {
            const { loc } = location;
            return this.getWeatherForecast(loc);
        }).then((forecast) => {
            const { currently, daily } = forecast;
            this.renderForecastInfo(currently, daily);
        });
    }
};

class GetWeatherForRandomCity extends Weather {
    constructor(city) {
        super();
        this.city = city;
    }

    makeRandom() {
        //code
    };

    init() {
        
        this.getCoordinates(this.makeRandom()).then(coords => {
            return this.getWeatherForecast(coords);
        }).then((forecast) => {
            const { currently, daily } = forecast;
            this.renderForecastInfo(currently, daily);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I would honestly recommend that you do not use `class`es and inheritance here at all. Just make a it a simple `function` that you can call, much more flexible.

Comment: @Bergi on my task I have to use inheritance

Comment: What a pity. Still, you can write a helper method `getAndRenderForecast` that take the coordinates of a location as an argument, and call that in your `init` methods to avoid code duplication.

Comment: read more about polymorphism in JS, see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391149/es6-classes-ability-to-perform-polymorphism

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just create `init` function in parent class and call it with parameter? Like this:

```js
class Weather {

    async getCoordinates(city) {
        //code
    }

    async getLocation() {
        //code
    }

    async getWeatherForecast(locationCoordinates) {
        //code
    }

    fahrenheitToCelsius(temp) {
        //code
    }

    renderForecastInfo(currently, daily) {
        //code
    }
    
    init(locationCoordinates) {
      this.getWeatherForecast(locationCoordinates)
        .then((forecast) => {
            const { currently, daily } = forecast;
            this.renderForecastInfo(currently, daily);
        });
    }
};

class GetWeatherForCurrentCity extends Weather {

    init() {
        this.getLocation().then((location) => {
            Weather.prototype.init.call(this, location.loc);
        });
    }
};

class GetWeatherForRandomCity extends Weather {
    constructor(city) {
        super();
        this.city = city;
    }

    makeRandom() {
        //code
    };

    init() {
        this.getCoordinates(this.makeRandom()).then(coords => {
            Weather.prototype.init.call(this, coords);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply you can move your function in the parent class, then re-declare it or overwrite it in the child class (this is called polymorphism one of the OOP concepts)